# How to stretch svg to 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following svg triangle:

```
<svg class="triangle" viewBox="0 0 2 2"><path d="M0,2 h2, v-2 Z"/></svg>
```

I added some styling to the svg, but the 100% width doesn't work...

```
.triangle {
  fill: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What's the height? Does `preserveAspectRatio = 'none'` help?

Comment: It works for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXojzw

Comment: Or this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qbLaoO

Comment: It does seem to miss some tags that are essential to some browsers (like the `xlmns`, `width` and `height`), but it does work in @TimTroiano codepen.

Comment: Are you sure you got a css reset? (the page itself has no margins or paddings)